# Session variable not set in test of Rails session controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, guard

I have extended my Devise::SessionsController in order to set a session variable when a user logs in. The session variable is not being set and my test isn't working.

seasons_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe SessionsController do
  it 'should store true in a session variable if birthdate is set' do
    person = FactoryGirl.create(:person, :birthdate)
    login_as(person)
    session[:birthdate].should eq(true)
  end

  it 'should store false in a session variable if birthdate is not set' do
    login_with create(:person)
    session[:birthdate].should eq(false)
  end
end
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
    class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    current_person.birthdate ? session[:birthdate] = true : session[:birthdate] = false
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

end
```

Error:

```
Failures:

  1) SessionsController should store true in a session variable if birthdate is set
     Failure/Error: session[:birthdate].should eq(true)

       expected: true
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4/lib/spring/commands/rspec.rb:18:in `call'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'

  2) SessionsController should store false in a session variable if birthdate is not set
     Failure/Error: session[:birthdate].should eq(false)

       expected: false
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4/lib/spring/commands/rspec.rb:18:in `call'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I'm at a loss as to why the variable is not set. Any help would be hugely appreciated. I'm new to testing.

Comment: you need to put `debugger` before the statement `current_person.birthdate ? session[:birthdate] = true : session[:birthdate] = false` and see if control reaches there. Because if it reaches there, your session variable would not be nil. It will be either true or false.

Comment: Thanks I did try that but no success. Since that line is in my controller not my test it doesn't do anything to add debugger

Comment: Although I have still be unable to get the test to work, I discovered that the session variable was not being set. I have no idea why but after changing to a cookie, it is being set. I have verified that in my browser console.

Comment: The debugger would stop, no matter where that line is, if the control reaches to that statement. Make sure you have `byebug` installed in test environment. If it not stopping at debugger it means the response is being sent before that statement.

Comment: The reason it didn't do anything is because that line is in my controller not my test

Comment: Again, it will stop wherever that line is. It not stopping means you are not able to reach to that statement when running your tests. Try putting it in first line of `create` method and see if it stops.

Comment: Yep you are right. Debugger stopped it. Gave me an error.